# Как вынести счётчик файлов в отдельный метод

Tags: c#, sqlite

Для начало прохожусь циклом по папкам и собираю файлы в `FilesF = new List<string>()`

```
public static void Sector()
{
   int y = 0;
   for (y = 0; y < class.FilesF.Count; y++) // это нужно вынести в отдельный метод.
   {
       // затем пробую подключаться к базе sqlite
       using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(Data, class.FilesF[y]))) 
       {
             con.Open();
       }
   }
}
```

Можно ли вынести цикл for в отдельный метод, а затем вызывать его и присваивать в `using(new SQLiteConnection(class.FilesF[Other_Method]))` ?

Comment: А разве for не в отдельном методе Sector? А что такое `class.` в for

Comment: Мне кажется foreach вам больше подойдёт

Comment: @codename0082016, я тоже так подумал), хотел вынести всё по отдельности для удобства.Просто внутри у меня ещё циклы `for` есть..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю что требуется сделать, но возможно что-то такое:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var FilesF = new List<string>();

        FilesF.ToList().ForEach(x => A(x));


    }
    public static void A(string i)
    {
        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(i)) { con.Open(); }
    }
}
```

Или Как-то так:

```
var FilesF = new List<string>();

foreach (var i in FilesF)
{
    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(i))
    {
        con.Open();
    }
}
```